# How to add gdx-tools to build.gradle in LibGdx?

Tags: libgdx

The GUI for TexturePacker isn't working for me, and I've been recommended to try it from my IDE instead. But after I created the class, I get errors on importing com.badlogic.gdx.tools; and on the TexturePacker class.

I read around on the internet, including here: [Can't add gdx-tools to libgdx gradle project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742328/cant-add-gdx-tools-to-libgdx-gradle-project) and the LibGDX wiki, but neither adding

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
```

to the desktop build.gradle nor replacing "$gdxVersion" with the actual version number, work for me, though that's what the wiki says.

More info: The errors I get are: On attempting to import gdx.tools: "The import com.badlogicgames.gdx.tools cannot be resolved". Then on TexturePacker is says "TexturePacker cannot be resolved".

I tried importing just the texturepacker library before, but the same story.

I refreshed my build gradle, but no change

Can anyone help please? It seems like it should be easy since I don't see many questions about it online, but it has stumped me.

Comment: Did you refresh your gradle files? Which errors are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added that info to the question. The import and the class say 'Cannot be resolved'.

Comment: what IDE do you use?

Comment: Which version of libGDX do you use here?